# How to move specific section of the element not entire element

Tags: magento2, extensions

I want to move the selected specific section of the element not the entire element,

```
<block class="Magefan\Blog\Block\Post\View" name="blog.post" template="post/view.phtml"/>
```

Common moving element

```
<move element="blog.post" destination="page.wrapper" before="main.content" />
```

I want to move only the **image section** not entire element,  **Blog post** contains image, title, description, etc. How to move only the specific scestion from element.

Answer (score 1):

In the layout XML use your block name as element and check for destination element use below line as per needed to you

```
<move element="name.of.an.element" destination="name.of.destination.element" as="new_alias" after="name.of.element.after" before="name.of.element.before"/>
```

Comment: Go to magefan template file and find $_post->getFeaturedImg() method move it on top then run, setup:upgrade command and clear cache

Comment: app\code\Magefan\Blog\view\frontend\templates\sidebar\recent.phtml,

Comment: <a class="post-item-link" title="<?= $_postName ?>" href="<?= $_postUrl ?>">

                            <img data-width-amp="<?= $width ?>" data-height-amp="<?= 

$height ?>" layout="responsive" src="<?= $imageHelper->init($_post-

>getFeaturedListImg() ?: $_post->getFeaturedImg())->resize($width, $height); ?>"

                                 alt="<?= $block->escapeHtml($featuredImgAlt) ?>" />

                        </a>

Comment: Hi arun, i am followed this link, image removed but image not placed under breadcrumbs, any help thanks. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/331550/57334

Comment: Do you create image.phtml file inside post directory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120041/discussion-between-zus-and-arun-kumar).

Comment: can you pls join chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120041/discussion-between-zus-and-arun-kumar

Comment: Do you create image.phtml file inside post directory? 
 --> yes join chat to view my code